# How can I run a Java IDE from a Docker container similar to RStudio Server?

Tags: java, docker, ide

I've become very used to developing R using the `rocker/rstudio` (https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/rstudio/) Docker images. I can start the container, link to my local directory with the project I'm working on, and then access Rstudio Server through my browser on localhost. No need for me to have R installed, and no need for me to have RStudio installed.

How can I do this with a Java IDE, such as Eclipse or IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a version of eclipse https://www.eclipse.org/che/ does provide web IDE and Docker version, still not mature enough.

Comment: I hadn't heard about this. Thanks! Looking into it now :)